# Typescript union of Map types

Tags: typescript

I have a key-union-type, and a value-union-type, and would like to create a Map object that maps one to another. With the simple approach, I lose some type information, though. Is it possible to define / enforce the concrete mapping types with typescript?

```
type CombinedKeyType = KeyTypeA | KeyTypeB;
type CombinedValueType = ValueTypeA | ValueTypeB;
const myBigMap: Map<CombinedKeyType, CombinedValueType> = new Map();
myBigMap.set(keyA, valueA); // works as expected
myBigMap.set(keyA, valueB); // Problem 1: No error is shown here, but it would be nice to get one
const myValue = myBigMap.get(keyA); // Problem 2: only has type "CombinedValueType", while it should be possible for TS to know that this variable is of type "ValueTypeA", right?
```

I already tried using a union type for the map itself, but this does not work either, as the types of the parameters of `.set(k,v)` are reduced to `never`;

```
const myBigMap: Map<KeyTypeA, ValueTypeA> | Map<KeyTypeB, ValueTypeB> = new Map();
```

Using an intersection type surprisingly works correctly for the `.set` method (Problem 1 solved?), but the `.get` method still returns a union type (Problem 2):

```
const myBigMap: Map<KeyTypeA, ValueTypeA> & Map<KeyTypeB, ValueTypeB> = new Map();
```

Can a correct type be defined within typescript for the kind of Map I want?

Comment: An intersection is probably what you want, or close to it, but  I can't be sure because the code here isn't a [mre] I can paste as-is into an IDE to play with.  Can you provide minimal definitions for your types?

Comment: Hmm, if I try to do this myself [I don't even see your problem](https://tsplay.dev/mbQBoN).  `Map` doesn't even have a `put()` method, so I guess your code here is just pseudocode?  What's the issue here, exactly?

Comment: Should we even be making heterogeneous maps?

Comment: (yes I meant 'set' instead of 'put')

Thank you for this example! It seems like using the union type just works like intended, perfect :)

Comment: But one thing that still does not work with this approach is to pass in an ambiguous key and get the ambiguous output type: 

declare const ambiguousKey: KeyTypeA | KeyTypeB;
const myAmbiguousValue = myBigMap.get(ambiguousKey);